# Populate database from internal project textfile wp7

Tags: mongodb, windows-phone-7

I implemented a mango database in my windows phone project.
I want to add data from an internal project file.
I tried to use the StreamReader

```
StreamReader L= new StreamReader ("/Data/info.txt");
```

But the problem still exists.
Is there a solution to resolve this problem?
Cordially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file 'File.txt' should be referenced as internal ressource.
In this case, 'test' is the project name.

```
var resource = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/test;component/File.txt", UriKind.Relative));
try
{
   StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
   string x = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   MessageBox.Show(x);
}
catch(Exception e)
{  
 MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```